# Swapping button images with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn various aspects of jQuery. I have a button with an id='contact' that I want to change its image on a mouse hover event.

```
<button id='contact' class='CXIII' onclick="btnContact()">
    <img id="logo" src="images/contact_blue.png">
</button>
```

I am using the following code, but when I hover over the button, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>   (anonymous function)
>  x.each.x.event.special.(anonymous
>   function).handle
> x.event.dispatch
>   x.event.add.y.handle

```
$("#contact").hover(
    function () {$(this).src = this.src.replace(contact_blue.src, contact_green.src);},
    function () {$(this).src = this.src.replace(contact_green.src, contact_blue.src);}
);
```

`contact_blue` and `contact_green` are global variables that hold references to images and are instantiated in a preloading function that I have tested and am confident in.

```
contact_green = new Image();
contact_blue  = new Image();

contact_green.src = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/update/images/contact_green.png";
contact_blue.src  = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/update/images/contact_blue.png";
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

p.s. I know that there are other ways to approach this (like CSS), but I am specifically trying to learn jQuery at the moment. Also,

EDIT: I tried both of these, unsuccessfully:

```
$("#contact").hover(
    function () {this.src = this.src.replace(contact_blue.src, contact_green.src);},
    function () {this.src = this.src.replace(contact_green.src, contact_blue.src);}
);


$("#contact").hover(
    function () {$(this).prop('src') = this.src.replace(contact_blue.src, contact_green.src);},
    function () {$(this).prop('src') = this.src.replace(contact_green.src, contact_blue.src);}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this

```
$(this).src
```

That's a jQuery object, and it has no `src` property, either do

```
this.src = new_source;
```

or

```
$(this).prop('src', new_source)
```

also, are you sure `contact_blue` and `contact_green` have a `src` property ?

However, the error message seems to indicate that `this.src` is undefined, and has no `replace` method, which is strange, are you sure `#contact` is an image element ?

#### EDIT:

Now that you've posted the HTML, the image is inside the button, so it's

```
$("#contact").hover(
    function () {
        var image = $(this).find('img').get(0);
        image.src = contact_green.src;
    },
    function () {
        var image = $(this).find('img').get(0);
        image.src = contact_blue.src;
    }
);
```

Note that `replace` replaces in strings, it doesn't swap the variables you're passing in ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried them both. The first gives me the exact same error. The second give me a similar error, except that it says `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: Yes, I am sure of that. I used them in another method successfully.

Comment: #contact is a button element that has an image assigned to it. I'll edit my OP to show it.

Comment: A button element has no `src` property ?

Comment: Thanks again. sorry about not posting the HTML originally. I used your code, but now nothing at happens. At least I don't get an error.

Comment: And what exactly is `contact_blue.src` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
   $(this).attr('src','New_Image_Path');
```